# Impress.js and AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, impress.js

I am running an AngularJS application/controller. My goal is to initialize and use the impress.js library on a page that is being dynamically loaded into my main home page. However, when I try to initialize the library, the page does not load. Attached is a snippet of the controller and html file.

NOTE: When I print the `impress()` object to the console, it is not null, and has the required functions. It is my suspicion that the `impress()` object is not hooking up to the page correctly.

Controller:

```
'use strict';

// Create the angular module
var cmodule = angular.module('coverage', ['ngRoute'])

// Create the coverage controller
cmodule.controller('coverageController', function($scope) {

    console.log("Entering controller");
    function require(script) {
        $.ajax({
            url: script,
            dataType: "script",
            async: true,           // <-- This is the key
            success: function () {
                console.log(impress());
                impress().init();
            },
            error: function () {
                throw new Error("Could not load script " + script);
            }
        });
    }

    console.log("About to require");
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        require("/content/libraries/impress.js");
            });


    });
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>My Coverage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/styles/team1.css">
</head>
<body class="impress-not-supported">
    <!--
    For example this fallback message is only visible when there is `impress-not-supported` class on body.
    -->
    <div class="fallback-message">
        <p>Your browser <b>doesn't support the features required</b> by impress.js, so you are presented with a simplified version of this presentation.</p>
        <p>For the best experience please use the latest <b>Chrome</b>, <b>Safari</b> or <b>Firefox</b> browser.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Now the fun begins -->

    <div id="impress">

        <!-- The background image -->
        <div class="present" data-x="0" data-y="0">
            <!-- Place Image here -->
        </div>

        <!-- Example content -->
        <div id="url-ident" class="step" data-x="0" data-y="0">
            <q>Ready to view your coverage?</q>
        </div>

        <!-- Example content -->
        <div id="step1" class="step" data-x="500" data-y="0">
            <p>Questions start here!</p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /div impress -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/libraries/impress.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--script type="text/javascript">impress().init();</script-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `impress()` is not an object but a function call. What you meant is probably `impress.init()`? The details of the error probably appeared in your browser's JS console, use this information as your first line of support before asking on SO.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, `impress()` is a function, and what I meant is that it returns an object, which has an `init()` method. Calling `impress.init()` gives an error "`impress.init` is not a function." This is outlined in the source code, saying "You also need to call a `impress().init()` function to initialize impress.js presentation." from https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/blob/master/index.html

Comment: So... What IS the error? What does the debugger console show?

Comment: Currently the debugger console does not give any errors. My console.log statements all print and the page loads, but the library does not bind to the id = "impress" div like it is suppose to, as explained in the impress.js source code. So everything runs without errors, but nothing actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was fixed by using the jmpress.js library instead, found [here](http://jmpressjs.github.io/jmpress.js/).